# CS1729 'Application' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created a OAuth2Service class in my Xamarin Forms Android Project which inherits a IOAuth2Service interface.I need this to be available in my class library so i can perform google authentication in my Xamarin forms Application. But I keep getting the error message mentioned above despite the fact that i setup the application class to accept an argument of type IOAuth2Service. Here's my "App.Xaml.cs" which contains the Application class. What should i do?

```
 public partial class Application : Xamarin.Forms.Application
    {
       public Application(IOAuth2Service oAuth2Service)
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage(oAuth2Service));

       }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            AppCenter.Start("android=ced94d85-cb85-4ec2-8411-96864a7ec23e;" +
                  "uwp={Your UWP App secret here};" +
                  "ios={Your iOS App secret here}",
                  typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
       }



    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620852/c-sharp-does-not-contain-a-constructor-that-takes-1-arguments

Answer (score 0):

Why not the instantiate the `OAuth2Service` class in the Constructor of `Application`like following code? Put `OAuth2Service` class in PCL.

```
    public Application()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       OAuth2Service oAuth2Service=new OAuth2Service (); 
       MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage(oAuth2Service));

   }
```

If `IOAuth2Service` in the xxxxx.Droid or xxxxx.IOS folder. You need transfer `IOAuth2Service` to the PCL. In Android, You can instantiate it in `OnCreate` method of `MainActivity.cs`

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        OAuth2Service oAuth2Service = new OAuth2Service ();
        LoadApplication(new App(oAuth2Service));
    }
```

In IOS, You can instantiate it in `FinishedLaunching` method of `AppDelegate.cs`

```
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

        OAuth2Service oAuth2Service = new OAuth2Service ();
        LoadApplication(new App(oAuth2Service));

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
```

Here is `Application` class.

```
  public partial class Application : Xamarin.Forms.Application
  {
   public Application(OAuth2Service oAuth2Service)
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage(oAuth2Service));

    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The IOAuth2Service is actually a Interface and not a class. I don't think you can create an instance object from an interface. And i'm correct cause after making the changes you suggested. I get the error:"Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'IOAuth2Service'"

Comment: Yes, that is my mistake, If `OAuth2Service`  is your class that inherits a IOAuth2Service interface. Please change `IOAuth2Service` to `OAuth2Service`, I updated my answer.Note:If you want to use `public Application(OAuth2Service oAuth2Service)` this way, your IOS project folder must have `OAuth2Service` class.

Comment: Actually fixed the issue by changing the subclass name from Application to App and updated the references